# Where should I attach solution or project events in my Visual Studio add-in?

Tags: visual-studio, events, add-in, extensibility

Can anyone suggest the best place to add solution or project events, such as ProjectAdded, to a Visual Studio add-in?

If I do this when the add-in connects then there's no solution loaded, so how can I tell when a solution has been loaded?

For example, if I write an event to handle project items being added, where should I attach this?  The event would be fired by the project, and that in turn by the solution, so I can't attach the events when the add-in connects because there is no solution when the add-in connects.

On the other hand, if I add them in the Exec() event then I need to do checks such as whether the event has been attached already, and I'm sure there must be a neater way sometime between the connection events and the Exec() event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably figured this out long ago, but anyway: You can setup your events from within `OnConnection` like shown below, this is a snippet of an Addin's Connect class (assuming you're using c#):

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;
using Extensibility;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommandBars;

namespace MyAddin1
{
  /// <summary>The object for implementing an Add-in.</summary>
  /// <seealso class='IDTExtensibility2' />
  public class Connect : IDTExtensibility2, IDTCommandTarget
  {
    private DTE2 _applicationObject;
    private AddIn _addInInstance;
    private SolutionEvents _solutionEvents;

    public void OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode,
          object addInInst, ref Array custom)
    {
      _applicationObject = (DTE2)application;
      _addInInstance = (AddIn)addInInst;

      // check the value of connectMode here, depending on your scenario
      if(connectMode == ...)
        SetupEvents();
    }

    private void SetupEvents()
    {
      // this is important ...
      _solutionEvents = _applicationObject.Events.SolutionEvents;

      // wire up the events you need
      _solutionEvents.Opened += new _dispSolutionEvents_OpenedEventHandler(_solutionEvents_Opened);
      _solutionEvents.AfterClosing += new _dispSolutionEvents_AfterClosingEventHandler(_solutionEvents_AfterClosing);
      _solutionEvents.ProjectAdded += new _dispSolutionEvents_ProjectAddedEventHandler(_solutionEvents_ProjectAdded);
    }

  // add procedures to handle the events here, plus any other
  // handling you need, ie. OnDisconnection and friends
}
```

The main point is, to wire up the solution and project events you need, it's not important if a solution or project is already loaded. They're not attached to any particular solution or project, they're provided by the Visual Studio object model and are embedded within the [EnvDTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) namespace.

It wouldn't make much sense to do anything else anyway, since you can configure an addin to load when VS starts, and in this case there will never ever be any solutions/projects loaded.

There's a few catches though:

- It's ***important*** that you keep a reference to the SolutionEvents class as a member variable within your connect class, otherwise [the events will never fire](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2005/MZ2005012.aspx), ([see also here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsx/thread/933efcb1-8032-40c4-b4f8-8afc6babd4da)).
- You need to make sure you check the `connectMode` parameter passed into `OnConnection`. This gets called multiple times with different parameters, and if you do it the wrong way you may get the event wired up multiple times, which definetly will be a problem. Also, usually any Addin IDE, like Menus and stuff, is set up from within `OnConnection`, so you may end up with duplicate menu items if you don't do it right.

Here's a few pointers, some of the code provided is VB code, in case you're looking for that:

- [HOWTO: Adding buttons, commandbars and toolbars to Visual Studio .NET from an add-in](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2005/MZ2005003.aspx)
- [HOWTO: Getting Project and ProjectItem events from a Visual Studio .NET add-in.](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2005/MZ2005009.aspx)
- [HOWTO: Add an event handler from a Visual Studio add-in](http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/MZ2008006.aspx)

Finally, here's a list of articles, about 70% of them cover basic and advanced topics regarding addins:

- [Resources about Visual Studio .NET extensibility](http://www.mztools.com/resources_vsnet_addins.aspx)

Find the section entitled *MZ-Tools Articles Series (about add-ins)* and have a look at what's covered there.