# Run a process after visual studio loads a solution

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to have Visual Studio 2013 run a process such as a batch file or other after a solution has been loaded ? and/or after a project has been loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a VS Addin Event. [This question has code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3471511/656243) demonstrating how to attach to the events. The [SolutionEventsClass.Opened Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.solutioneventsclass.opened.aspx) would probably work for you.

After hooking the event, you can execute any code that you want...